# Is it possible to do some conditional binding in SAPUI5 based on parent element?

Tags: sapui5

I have an XML fragment and use it in several places in an XML view like this:

```
<IconTabFilter text="ABC" key="1" icon="sap-icon://alphabetical-order">
    <content>
        <Table id="table1" width="auto" items="{path:'/ContactSet',parameters:{expand:'BusinessAddress,HomeAddress,OtherAddress,Photo'},filters:[{path:'Surname',operator:'StartsWith',value1:'A'},{path:'Surname',operator:'StartsWith',value1:'B'},{path:'Surname',operator:'StartsWith',value1:'C'}]}" noDataText=" {worklistView>/tableNoDataText}" busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" updateFinished="onUpdateFinished">
            <headerToolbar>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="de.cimt.cimply.AddressBook.view.worklist.tablesHeader" type="XML"/>
            </headerToolbar>
            <columns>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="de.cimt.cimply.AddressBook.view.worklist.tablesColumns" type="XML"/>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="de.cimt.cimply.AddressBook.view.worklist.tablesRows" type="XML"/>
            </items>
        </Table>
    </content>
</IconTabFilter>
<IconTabSeparator icon="sap-icon://process"/>
<IconTabFilter text="DEF" key="2" icon="sap-icon://alphabetical-order">
    <content>
        <Table id="table2" width="auto" items="{path:'/ContactSet',parameters:{expand:'BusinessAddress,HomeAddress,OtherAddress,Photo'},filters:[{path:'Surname',operator:'StartsWith',value1:'D'},{path:'Surname',operator:'StartsWith',value1:'E'},{path:'Surname',operator:'StartsWith',value1:'F'}]}" noDataText="{worklistView>/tableNoDataText}" busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" updateFinished="onUpdateFinished">
            <headerToolbar>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="de.cimt.cimply.AddressBook.view.worklist.tablesHeader" type="XML"/>
            </headerToolbar>
            <columns>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="de.cimt.cimply.AddressBook.view.worklist.tablesColumns" type="XML"/>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="de.cimt.cimply.AddressBook.view.worklist.tablesRows" type="XML"/>
            </items>
        </Table>
    </content>
</IconTabFilter>
```

I have some bindings in `tablesHeader` fragment file:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Toolbar>
        <Title text="{worklistView>/worklistTableTitle}"/>
        <ToolbarSpacer/>
        <SearchField tooltip="{i18n>worklistSearchTooltip}" search="onSearch" width="auto"/>
    </Toolbar>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Now the question is how can I customize the binding inside the fragment based on its parent element. 
For example I would like to have `<Title text="{worklistView>/worklistTable1Title}"/>` when it is placed inside the `IconTabFilter` with `key="1"` and also `<Title text="{worklistView>/worklistTable2Title}"/>` when it placed inside the `IconTabFilter` with `key="2"`.

One possibility is to pass this binding to the fragment when we place it in the destination. But I don't know do we have any option for that in `SAPUI5` or not.

The other possibility is to use some kinds of templating like what explained [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon10/1.17/en-US/5e/e619fc1370463ea674ee04b65ed83b/content.htm?no_cache=true). However, again I don't know how to make the conditions based on the parent element.

Note: I don't want to enter the codes inside the fragment file directly in the destination file, as I want to prevent repeating the code.

Comment: `worklistView` is the JSON model right?

Comment: Yes, it is a JSON model that bind to view to control some behaviors of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play with the `worklistView` JSON model. As you mentioned it is a JSON model there will be a common property which is bind to the header text control irrespective of the selected key.

On load `IconTabBar` will set the default `key` using `selectedKey` property. So we can set this `key` value as the default value for the header text in the header section.

**view.xml**

```
<IconTabBar
    id="idIconTabBar"
    select="handleIconTabBarSelect"
    selectedKey="1"
    class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
    <items>
        <IconTabFilter text="ABC" key="1" icon="sap-icon://alphabetical-order">
            <content>
                <Table id="table1" width="auto"  noDataText=" {worklistView>/tableNoDataText}" busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" updateFinished="onUpdateFinished">
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <core:Fragment fragmentName="path/tablesHeader" type="XML"/>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <!-- columns-->
                    <!-- items -->
                </Table>
            </content>
        </IconTabFilter>
        <IconTabSeparator icon="sap-icon://process"/>
        <IconTabFilter text="DEF" key="2" icon="sap-icon://alphabetical-order">
            <content>
                <Table id="table2" width="auto"  noDataText="{worklistView>/tableNoDataText}" busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" updateFinished="onUpdateFinished">
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <core:Fragment fragmentName="path/tablesHeader" type="XML"/>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <!-- columns-->
                    <!-- items -->
                </Table>
            </content>
        </IconTabFilter>
    </items>
</IconTabBar>
```

**Header fragment**

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Toolbar>
        <Title text="{worklistView>/worklistTableHdrTitle}"/>
        <ToolbarSpacer/>
        <SearchField tooltip="{i18n>worklistSearchTooltip}" search="onSearch" width="auto"/>
    </Toolbar>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

**controller.js**

`worklistView` model will be set with an extra property `worklistTableHdrTitle` with the default value as per the `key` which is mentioned in the `IconTabBar`.

```
setworklistViewModel: function() {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData({
      "worklistTableHdrTitle": "Table1 Title",//default value, as selectedKey="1" in IconTabBar 
      "worklistTable1Title": "Table1 Title",
      "worklistTable2Title": "Table2 Title",
      "tableNoDataText": "No Data"
    });
    this.getView().setModel(oModel, "worklistView");
  },
```

Manipulate the `worklistView` model data based on the selection.

```
  handleIconTabBarSelect: function(oEvent) { 
    var sSelectedKey = oEvent.getParameters("selectedKey").key;
    if (sSelectedKey) {
      var oModel = this.getView().getModel("worklistView");
      if (oModel) 
        oModel.setProperty("/worklistTableHdrTitle", (sSelectedKey === "1") ? oModel.getProperty("/worklistTable1Title") : oModel.getProperty("/worklistTable2Title"));
    }
  },
```

Comment: Clever idea and solution, but still I am looking forward to hear something about templating in XML view. I hope there would be some solutions to do this purely in Fragment and XML view. Assume we have the both tables in the same tab or when we don't have any tab and user can see all the repeated items in a glance. So I will vote up your answer but let me not accept it as the final answer.